# Developing stable HTML5 Offline Applications?

Tags: html, offline

I am planning to offer a [web page that can be launched without an internet connection](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline), however, I am unsure about the stability of the cache that the browser will supply.

If I visit [this page](http://htmlfive.appspot.com/static/stickies.html) in Google Chrome, it appears to download all the resources necessary, so I can later re-visit that page without an internet connection.

My question is, How can I prevent the cache being randomly removed by the browser due to aging or space utilization or other reasons? Will a manifest be sufficient? What kind of usage limits are imposed?

Also, if you can let me know what the browser support requirements are, including mobile browsers, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide an offline web page don't rely on the browser cache because it's not under your control. The cache management is a complex process and varies between browsers.

Rather use HTML5 client-side storage such as [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) for NoSQL key-value storage or the [FileSystem API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html) which gives you access to a sandboxed sections of the local filesystem.